# Tasking support in CortexM4-based board

Tags: ada

I am experimenting with tasking in a Cortex M4 based board (specifically a `stm32f429I` one) but it looks like the runtime I'm using doesn't allow task hierarchy (which kind of make sense). To give a bit more context, I've written the following procedure:

```
procedure Flash_LED_With_Randevouz is
   
   type LED_Colour is (Red, Green);
   
   task type LED_Controller(LC: LED_Colour) is
      
      entry Turn_LED_On;
      
      entry Turn_LED_Off;
      
   end LED_Controller;
   
   task body LED_Controller is      
   begin
      -- Setup port clock, pin mode etc here based on "LC" value
      loop
         accept Turn_LED_On do
            null;
         end Turn_LED_On;
      
         accept Turn_LED_Off do
            null;
         end Turn_LED_Off;
      end loop;
   end LED_Controller;
   
   RC: LED_Controller(Red);
   GC: LED_Controller(Green);
begin
   null;
end Flash_LED_With_Randevouz;
```

(and there would be client tasks calling these entries). My `gprbuild` file looks like that:

```
project Embedded is

   for Languages use ("Ada", "Asm");
   for Main use ("flash_led_with_randevouz.adb");
   for Source_Dirs use ("src/**");
   for Object_Dir use "obj";
   for Target use "arm-eabi";
   for Runtime ("Ada") use "ravenscar-full-stm32f429disco";

   package Compiler is
      for Default_Switches ("Ada") use ("-O0", "-g", "-gnatwa", "-gnatQ", "-gnatw.X");
   end Compiler;

   package Builder is
      for Default_Switches ("Ada") use ("-g");
      for Global_Configuration_Pragmas use "gnat.adc";
   end Builder;

   package Ide is
      for Connection_Tool use "st-util";
      for Program_Host use "localhost:4242";
      for Communication_Protocol use "remote";
   end Ide;

end Embedded;
```

And when I try to build, I get the following errors:

```
Compile
   [Ada]          flash_led_with_randevouz.adb
flash_led_with_randevouz.adb:5:04: warning: objects of this type will violate "No_Task_Hierarchy" [enabled by default]
flash_led_with_randevouz.adb:7:07: error: violation of implicit restriction "Max_Task_Entries = 0"
flash_led_with_randevouz.adb:18:10: error: construct not allowed in configurable run-time mode
flash_led_with_randevouz.adb:18:10: error: file s-tasren.ads not found
flash_led_with_randevouz.adb:18:10: error: entity "System.Tasking.Rendezvous.Exceptional_Complete_Rendezvous" not available
flash_led_with_randevouz.adb:28:04: error: violation of restriction "No_Task_Hierarchy"
flash_led_with_randevouz.adb:28:04: error: from profile "Jorvik" at system.ads:42
flash_led_with_randevouz.adb:29:04: error: violation of restriction "No_Task_Hierarchy"
flash_led_with_randevouz.adb:29:04: error: from profile "Jorvik" at system.ads:42
gprbuild: *** compilation phase failed
```

I tried looking into my GNAT installation for any clues for available runtimes and found a number of directories under `2021-arm-elf/arm-eabi/lib/gnat/` which I *think* correspond to the available runtimes that can be specified in the build file? These all fall under two main categories i.e. `ravenscar*` and `zfp*` ones (I assume these are the ones with floating-point support?) and as, as far as I know, the Ravenscar ones don't support task hierarchies, I gave some of the `zfp` ones a try but got similar errors (there seem to be some more generic Cortex-M4 and some board-specific ones).

So, I was wondering how available runtimes can be discovered and if there're any tips on how to go about finding a runtime (if one exists) that supports multi-tasking for this board. - Thanks

Comment: GNAT embedded run-times are ZFP (Zero Foot Print), Ravenscar and Jovik. ZFP has no tasking. Ravenscar (or Ravenscar SFP) has very limited tasking support. Jorvik (or Ravenscar FULL) has a little bit less limits on tasking support. More info [here](https://docs.adacore.com/gnathie_ug-docs/html/gnathie_ug/gnathie_ug/the_predefined_profiles.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to read the documentation. For GNAT GPL Edition 2021 you can find it in the installation folder `<INSTALL>/share/doc/gnat-cross/html/gnat_ugx/gnat_ugx.html`. See "Chapter 4 The Predefined Profiles". ZFP is Zero Footprint Profile. It has no support for tasking. Ravenscar has some tasking support, but you should move tasks to a package of the library level.

AdaCore changed runtime names recently (see [documentation](https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gnat_ugx/html/gnat_ugx/gnat_ugx.html)). It could be simpler for you to install GNAT 13.2 or GNAT 12.2 using [alire](https://alire.ada.dev/) and start with it then relearn after GNAT GPL 2021.

Comment: Ok, great, will go through these documents first and try to make this work without Alire (mostly for educational purposes) and then give Alire a try. Thanks very much.